# Why doesn't python premailer process this HTML + styles properly?

Tags: python, premailer

I have the following very basic CSS/HTML. When I point my browser to it, displays the letters ABC properly with foreground and background colors.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <style>
        .myStyleClass {
           background:Pink;
           color:Black;
        }
        .myStyleClass table thead th {
            background-color:Red;
            color:Blue;
        }
        .myStyleClass table tbody th {
            background-color:Green;
            color:Yellow;
        }
        .myStyleClass table tbody td {
           background:Purple;
           color:White;
        }
    </style>
      <div class="myStyleClass">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">A</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I feed this to the python Premailer package, however the output HTML it gives me lacks almost all of the formatting:

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="background: Pink;
color: Black">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">A</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>B</th>
<td>C</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why didn't premailer work? Isn't this exactly what it is designed to do? All the letters show up with black font.

Comment: May be stating the obvious, but take a look at exactly what is rendered in the output, and what is given in the input. It looks as if the output only pulls the attributes and values explicitly defined in the input.

Comment: So it cannot deal with inheritance of CSS as I defined?

Comment: I realize this question is a little old, but when I feed the HTML above into the latest version of premailer.transform(), it correctly adds the style attributes to the th and td tags. Whether because I did something differently from you, or whether because there was previously some bug in premailer, remains a mystery.